# Rate Distortion Minimization in a Python Clustering Algorithm

Tags: python, financial-engineering, cluster, rate-distortion

I'm attempting to solve for $\hat{k}$ clusters, such that the rate distortion is minimized, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set), however, the answers that I am getting from my algorithm are not following the "Jump" behavior (as is needed to appropriately choose $k$).

**My current process:**

Given a $N$ by $d$ matrix of asset returns:

1. Calculate the correlation of the assets, resulting in a $d \times d$ correlation matrix.
2. For $k \in [1, d]$ calculate the $1 \times d$ vectors of cluster labels, using the correlation matrix as the input
3. For $k \in [1, d]$ calculate $k, 1 \times d$ vectors of cluster centroids, using the correlation matrix as the input
4. Based on the cluster label (see code below), construct $\mathbf{A}$, a $d \times d$ matrix of cluster centroids based on the cluster label of each asset.  So for instance, say $k=3$ and there are 4 assets total, and the results of the k-means cluster is:

   - asset 1 is in cluster 1
   - asset 2 is in cluster 1
   - asset 3 is in cluster 2
   - asset 4 is in cluster 3

     I would create a $4 \times 4$ matrix where $\textrm{row }1 = \textrm{centroid } 1$ (a 1, 4 row vector), $\textrm{row }2 = \textrm{centroid } 1$ $\textrm{row }3 = \textrm{centroid } 2$ (a 1, 4 row vector), $\textrm{row }4 = \textrm{centroid} 3$
5. Then calculate the **rate distortion** function, $\epsilon$, for each $k$, where:

   $\epsilon_{k} \triangleq \frac{1}{p}\mathbf{A^\intercal}\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}\mathbf{A}$
      where, $\mathbf{\Sigma} \triangleq$ The Covariance Matrix of the $N \times d$ asset returns **NOTE:** I'm not certain whether I take the covariance of the asset returns or the covariance of the covariance matrix (which didn't seem right to me).
6. This leaves me with a $d \times d$ matrix that I then sum all the values, and follow the remainder of the procedure listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set).  This procedure is derived from the paper, [Finding the number of clusters in a data set: An information theoretic approach](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.107.9895%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=EwqJUZS4M9ey4AOI6oHQCw&v6u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com%2Fgen_204%3Fip%3D64.49.98.2%26ts%3D1367935508309732%26auth%3Dr5qjolgubxkfxpxipmyymjjw2wqtvlb5%26rndm%3D0.16257459507323802&v6s=2&v6t=2984&usg=AFQjCNFGfk0V7cG6e0DvAi9WTdkU8-zkUw&sig2=Ej2qQ9c-ohnr1fnrU679Cg&bvm=bv.45960087,d.dmg)

My Python Code is as follows:

```
import Pycluster

def rate_distortion(X, cov_matrix, num_clusters):
    clusterid, error, nfound = Pycluster.kcluster(X, nclusters = num_clusters)
    cdata, cmask = Pycluster.clustercentroids(X, clusterid = clusterid)
    c_mat = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.empty(X.shape), columns = X.columns)
    for i, cluster in enumerate(clusterid):
        c_mat.ix[i, :] = cdata[cluster, :]

    diff_mat = numpy.subtract(X, c_mat)
    p = X.shape[1]
    Y = p/2.
    distortion = 1./p * numpy.sum(numpy.dot(numpy.dot(diff_mat.transpose(),
                                                      numpy.linalg.inv(cov_matrix)),
                                            diff_mat))
    return distortion**(-Y)
```

To execute a script that exactly illustrates to what I'm referring to, use data located [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvvtlo2f23vx0fp/asset_prices.csv) and the following script:

```
import pandas, numpy, Pycluster

prices = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('asset_prices.csv')
returns = prices.apply(numpy.log).diff()
k = numpy.arange(1,12)
d = []
for i in k:
      d.append(rate_distortion(returns.corr(), returns.cov(), i)
d = pandas.Series(d, index = k)

In [22]: d
Out[22]:
1     8.845139e-33
2     3.969062e-29
3     9.387323e-28
4     9.200729e-28
5     4.675902e-18
6     2.412458e-21
7     3.582043e-18
8     8.094695e-17
9     1.424341e-16
10    4.320064e-14
11             inf
dtype: float64
```

Comment: any chance you could post your data?

Comment: Just posted the data, as well as a small script to show you exactly what I'm seeing (as well as the output).  Thanks for the suggestion @quasi

Comment: So I'm a little confused.  You're using $\Sigma$ as your underlying data, with each row a data point.  So you have $d$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  But in your dispersion calculation, you're not using the covariance matrix of $\Sigma$, you're using $\Sigma$ itself.  This seems to not be the algorithm.

Comment: The naive application of the paper you cited seems to be: calculate $\Sigma$ as you did, then use the distortion measure to cluster the $d$-dimensional returns as a function of time.

Comment: @quasi, thanks for the reply.  A little clarification, $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ as I've defined it, is the covariance matrix as an input to the distortion calculation.  The clustering algorithm is being run on the **correlation matrix** of asset returns.

So you're saying, I should set $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ equal to the Covariance of the correlation matrix (which is the input to my clustering algorithm), instead of the covariance of asset returns (which I'm currently doing), correct?

Comment: Right sorry, what you said is right.  But your "observations" aren't independent now.  Not sure how that will affect things.

Comment: When you say my "observations aren't independent _now_", I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I'm running a clustering algorithm on a correlation matrix, which I would call my "observations," and asset returns in finance are rarely (if ever) independent, so I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I guess I meant that now they're algebraically dependent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8670/discussion-between-factor3-and-quasi)

Comment: Pycluster seems to be gone from PyPI but a .tar.gz can be found here: http://www.filewatcher.com/m/Pycluster-1.50.tar.gz.271532-0.html

Comment: @benjaminmgross I'm interested in this question. Can you put the data back on Dropbox?

Comment: @BobJansen, they're just Adj Close asset prices.  Something like: data = pandas.io.dataDataReader(['IWB','IWR','IWM','SCZ','EFA','EEM','TIP','TLT','IEF,'SHY','HYG','LQD','PCY','BWX','MBB','PFF','IYR','GLD','GSG'])['Adj Close'] should give you wide array of asset classes to set up (nearly) the same problem I was working on.  And as an aside, I do see the [PyCluster Library on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pycluster).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check. I see the PyPI page but `pip` errors and the links are not useful. Also, PyPI refers to 1.49 while 1.50 is available...

Comment: @BobJansen, hmmmm, that's very true (my current version is 1.52)  Although, because my implementation is a simple k-cluster, centroid / distance algorithm, [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) should accomplish things fine as well.  Let me know if you'd like to work on the idea in parallel, it'd  be a fun project to collaborate on.

Comment: Would indeed be fun but this is a busy week for me. I'll let you hear something soonish